# remove the yeoman image from browser

Tags: angularjs, yeoman

I used Yeoman to create a web app in AngularJS. Everything works ok, but after using the grunt build command, if I view the built app in the browser (from dist directory), I can see that some yeoman image on the broswer, how i can remove it?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for a line that looks like this in your index.html in your public folder.

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="../img/favicon.ico">
```

and change the href to wherever your image is, or to remove it just delete that line.

Comment: Thank you but i don't have this block in my index.html and i have placed the index.html in the above question for reference.

Comment: I see this icon as well.  There is no such icon in the directory, there is no favicon link in index.html AND I cleared chrome's cache.

Answer (score 3):

Delete Chrome's favicon cache file.

On the Mac, it's at

`/Users/[yourname]/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Favicons`

Answer (score 2):

You only have to do this steps:

1. Delete the file called favicon.ico (it's in the dir called "app")
2. If you have the image you want to use as a favicon, go to this [link](http://www.favicon.cc/)
3. Click on "create a favicon" and upload your image.
4. This page will generate your favicon in a file named "favicon" and you have to save it in the same place where you deleted the file favicon of yeoman.